# Tabs layout in Django

Tags: django, tabs

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">


  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Baby computer Man</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. It is often the first program written by people learning to code.</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">The Manchester Baby, also known as the Small-Scale Experimental Machine, was the world's first electronic stored-program computer. It was built at the University of Manchester, UK, by Frederic C. Williams, Tom Kilburn, and Geoff Tootill, and ran its first program on 21 June 1948, seventy-one years ago</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">...</div>
  </div>


</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

In this code the second and the third tabs do not show the content when i click them. It seems the href is not working. Could you please explain what is wrong with it?

Also how can i position the tabs menu in the middle of the page? Through CSS? Could you please show some example of code or give any tips?

Thank you

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Can you post a picture? I put your HTML in a test file and it worked as expected. My only hunch is that your bootstrap may not be loading from your load tag. I usually just link the CDN in the head instead.

Comment: the Home tab shows the content but when i click "Baby computer Man" tab it does not show the content. Why is that? Is the href wrong or what is the worng with the code? I can't understand. Would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine when I replace your `{% load bootstrap4 %}` tag with the [bootstrap CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#css). That means you must have set up that tag incorrectly.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Baby computer Man</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. It is often the first program written by people learning to code.</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">The Manchester Baby, also known as the Small-Scale Experimental Machine, was the world's first electronic stored-program computer. It was built at the University of Manchester, UK, by Frederic C. Williams, Tom Kilburn, and Geoff Tootill, and ran its first program on 21 June 1948, seventy-one years ago</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There're a lot of ways to center elements. Try a few different methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically) and see which one you like best.